# How to get session ID from HttpClient instance?

Tags: c#, http, onvif

I am using an `Onvif-supported` camera and am controlling it using `onvif wsdl's` (specifically `ImagingService`, `Media10`, and `PTZ`). These work great for controlling most aspects of the camera, but there are a few settings that I want to modify that do not seem to be supported by my camera's version of Onvif.

Onvif works by sending `soap requests/packets` to the camera. However, when I used `Wireshark` and observed what happens when I use the software the camera came with, I noticed it works by `sending http GET/POST requests` containing `FormUrlEncoded` messages, and one of the fields is labelled `session,` presumably the session ID for the connection. I was able to recreate the message that the camera's software sends, send it, and confirm that my settings change. However, whenever a new session starts (different ID), it no longer works, and my http response contains:

```
{"error":{"code":287637505,"message":"Invalid session in request data!"},"result":false}
```

In other words, hard coding the session Id that I got through wireshark was the only way I could get it to work, but as soon as the session changes it no longer works. I was wondering if there was a way to easily get the session ID, store it as a variable, and then just place it within my messages. I would hope this would be possible either through the `HttpClient`, or any of the three Onvif clients I am using (`MediaClient`, `ImagingClient`, or `PTZClient`).

I have tried searching through many of the methods/fields in each of the clients above, creating HttpWebRequests, looking through the response messages for `GET & POST`, looking around where the login credentials are kept, and creating a Cookie with the info.

The way I go about setting everything up is rather simple:

```
private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

var msg = $"{{\"method\":\"configManager.setConfig\",\"params\":{{\"name\":\"VideoInExposure\",\"table\":" +
                $"[[{{\"AntiFlicker\":2,\"Compensation\":50,\"DoubleExposure\":0,\"Gain\":50,\"GainMax\":2,\"GainMin\":0," +
                $"\"GlareInhibition\":0,\"Iris\":50,\"IrisAuto\":true,\"IrisMax\":30,\"IrisMin\":0,\"Mode\":4,\"RecoveryTime\":900," +
                $"\"SlowAutoExposure\":50,\"SlowShutter\":false,\"SlowSpeed\":30,\"Speed\":0,\"Value1\":250,\"Value2\":250," +
                $"\"WideDynamicRange\":0,\"WideDynamicRangeMode\":0}}}]],\"options\":[]}},\"id\":6123,\"session\":\"4ec9a21aac415eead620ab163141fa03\"}}";

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://192.168.100.233/RPC2", new StringContent(msg, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

Where the portion labeled `session` at the end of the message is the string that I need to obtain.

I was hoping this property would be stored somewhere accessible, either in the client, or within a response if I just do a simple GET command, but I have not yet found this to be the case. Any help is greatly appreciated!

edit: I have also tried getting this value from the soap commands that `Onvif` already uses, with no luck so far. But if there is a way to do it that way I am very open to it.

Comment: session ids are generally server side

Comment: That makes sense, however if it is contained in the request that the camera's software sends, you would think it would be accessible in some way, since it is required in some types of requests, unless I'm missing something big.

Comment: @k1jj if that `sessionId` is part of the API, then there should be an API (probably at the beginning on the connection, on the authentication/authorization handshake) which requests "something" (either a POST or a GET request) and has that session id on the response. There's no such thing as a "session id" on an "general" http request, so there's no way any http client would have that for you (unless it's a specific one of the API you are using). Try "wiresharking" the initial connection and see the initial handshake/authorization and its responses: it should be there